# Parallel stored procedure execution in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, stored-procedures, multiprocessing, gevent

I have a web application with following setup:

Django 2.1.7 web application. I'm using gunicorn as my web server. Script to startup gunicorn server:

> gunicorn project_config.wsgi:application --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000  --workers=8

I have concurrent API requests (It does some heavy processing, but mostly it is stored procedure calls - most time spent in doing IO).
So when serving multiple API calls, I'm running multiple stored procedure calls parallely.

Since I'm starting up my gunicorn server using gevent worker class, it creates 8 worker processes (not green-threads). Which means there is no context switching happening between each API requests. 
But my stored procedure call execution time doubles with number of API calls. So essentially an API request which gets completed is 10 minutes, takes 20 minutes if there is another API call getting served parallely. Similarly if there are 3 requests being served parallely, the same request takes 30mins to complete.

Initially I thought this is something to do with multi-threading and GIL lock, as python threads do not actually run parallely. But when I print the PID (using os.getpid()), each requests prints unique PID (pid of the gevent worker process), which means they are being processed in separate processes and it should run parallely.

My stored procedure is a complex select statement. It does not perform any DELETE/UPDATE query, which means there is no locking involved as well. 
Why then my stored procedure execution time increases with every requests added up.

Even when I do

```
SELECT * from information_schema.PROCESSLIST;
```

It shows me number of MYSQL processes that are executing currently and this number is exacly same as number of API requests, which again means there are stored procedure calls running in parallel.

Output of above statement:

```
ID       COMMAND  TIME  STATE                   INFO
338470   Query    9     Creating sort index     SELECT *  FROM ....
338312   Query    1     Sending data            SELECT *  FROM ....
338311   Query    4     Sending data            SELECT *  FROM ....
```

Comment: *"most time spent in doing IO"* Is this a guess or did you measure that/does it make sense from what you are doing? (Disk) I/O is usually a bottleneck, and could explain your behaviour if one process is already using 100% of the available resources.

Comment: The MySQL PROCESSLIST is not the same as the Python client's process. MySQL runs in a single OS process, and what they term "process" in the information schema are actually threads in the mysqld process. There is one thread per client connection. These threads do run in parallel where possible, although they might block each other temporarily if they are contending for the same locks or mutexes.

Comment: Also, a given client connection can only run its queries (including those in a stored procedure) in a single thread in mysqld. The client sessions run in parallel with respect to each other, but within one session, they run their queries with no parallelism.

Comment: @BillKarwin As you said MySQL PROCESSLIST shows the threads in mysqld process and also that each connection creates a single thread and so one connection can run 1 query at a time. But PROCESSLIST is showing 3 rows, which means 3 connections which means 3 queries running in parallel, am I right ??

Comment: Correct, each session represents a different client connection. It's possible for one client to have more than one MySQL connection, but it's not typical code design for Python apps. It would be more common in a language the supports multiple threads better, like Java or Go or C++.

Comment: Regardless of the language, it's a good idea if you have multiple threads running in your client app, to have each of them open their own connection to the database. MySQL protocol is stateful, so if you have multiple client threads trying to share a single connection, it causes confusion because one thread might submit a new query while another thread is fetching results from its earlier query. The protocol can't sort all that out, so you could end up getting the wrong results unpredictably. Therefore each client thread should have its own connection to keep them straight.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, but I'm using multiprocessing here. So my client is opening multiple connection to the database on each requests. As I said when I get 3 API calls at the same time, SHOWPROCESSLIST shows 3 connections running in MySQL

Comment: There will be one row in MySQL's SHOW PROCESSLIST for each client connection.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, but there are 3 rows, so 3 connections and 3 parallel execution. But it is not executing in parallel, I found out the reason which is I have only 1 CPU core in MySQL instance. 1 CPU core is limiting only 1 query execution at a time. So essentially my MySQL connections are running concurrently and not parallely. Am I giving the correct reason?

Comment: The processlist shows the state of each session, and they appear to be running. But that's because it's really just showing the value of a state variable for each thread. The last time the MySQL thread had CPU context, it set its state variable to a running state. Then the OS might have switched context to another thread, but the thread is still "running" even though it isn't making any progress until its thread gets CPU context back.